# Hadoop workload

Tags: hadoop, cpu, workload

I am currently using wordcount application in hadoop as a benchmark. I find that the cpu usage is fairly nearly constant around 80-90%. I would like to have a fluctuating cpu usage. Is there any hadoop application that can give me this capability? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it that high when the Job is running, or all the time? Why do you want to limit the CPU hadoop uses?

Comment: I dont want to limit the cpu hadoop uses. I want the hadoop's cpu usage to be fluctuating between some range like 60-90 or something like that. It is that high only when the job is running. I want some job that can create such a fluctuation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to throttle or specify a range for hadoop to use. Hadoop will use the CPU available to it. When I'm running a lot of jobs, I'm constantly in the 90%+ range.

One way you can control the CPU usage is to change the maximum number of mappers/reducers each tasktracker can run simultaneously. This is done through the 
`mapred.tasktracker.{map|reduce}.tasks.maximum` setting in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml`.

It will use less CPU on that tasktracker when the number of mapper/reducers is limited.

Another way is to set the configuration value for `mapred.tasktracker.{map|reduce}.tasks` when setting up the job. This will force that job to use that many mappers/reducers. This number will be split across the available tasktrackers, so if you have 4 nodes and want each node to have 1 mapper you'd set `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks` to `4`.  It's also possible that if a node can run 4 mappers, it will run all 4, I don't know exactly how hadoop will split out the tasks, but forcing a number, per job, is an option.

I hope that helps get you to where you're going. I still don't quite understand what you are looking for. :)

Comment: No, I dont want to lower Hadoop CPU usage. Now I want  it to keep changing between 50-90 or something. Like Say one crude way to explain this using an example is : Say if im using 4 map tasks (at a time - like I can specify in mapred-site.xml). And cpu usage of that is 90%. In run time i can change that to 3 , 2 every minute and increase it. Now CPU will from from 90 to say 80 and then to 70. And as we increase it will also increase. But I am not trying to do this. It will be good to have a workload that utilizes CPU in such fashion . Clear ? Basically I want to use hadoop as a benchmark.

Comment: @sethu: I do not believe you can change it during a job's process. If you construct something to run your job where you can pass in how many tasks to do (via the job specific setting mentioned in my post) you will be able to control it per job and look at performance of the same job with different numbers of `tasks` allocated to it. It's still a little fuzzy what you are trying to do exactly. Sorry for being dense on this, I'm missing a piece for it to make sense.